# Javascript class libraries "mimic"

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm starting using OO concepts in Javascript.

So, I have several "class" js files, each node defining a single "class" as:

```
// FILE myproject.classlib.myClass1

// "Class"
function myClass1(param1, param2){

   // Properties
   this.prop1 = param1;
   this.prop2 = param2;
}

/// "Methods"
myClass1.prototype.doSomething = function(){

    alert('myClass1 Hello world. prop1=' = this.prop1);
    alert('myClass1 Hello world. prop2=' = this.prop2);
}
```

At the end on my HTML page where the classes are used I have to add several js files, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="/Content/script/mzui.myproject.classlib.myClass1.js")" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="/Content/script/mzui.myproject.classlib.myClass2.js")" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="/Content/script/mzui.myproject.classlib.myClass3.js")" />
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="/Content/script/mzui.myproject.classlib.myClassN.js")" />
```

At the end all files will become a single myproject.jar using Google´s Closure Compiler, but I need to keep my development environment structured, avoiding also double definitions at run time.

So, what shall be done to:

1. Organize classes into "namespaces". I've searched and I could build a single project object, but how can I reference the same object in all files (to add the classes) ?
2. What can be done to avoid too many  tags in all of my screens ? Is there a way to "bundle" them in a single javascript that will load all others ?

Comment: See http://browserify.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already planning on using the Closure Compiler, I have some very specific suggestions about how to do file / dependency management.

1. If you check out some code written to the Google Closure style, you'll see how they define namespaces and use `goog.provide()` and `goog.require()` to declare what will be used outside of the file defining it and what a file needs from other parts of the codebase.
2. I strongly recommend using the Closure Compiler and the Closure Library through [plovr](http://plovr.com/about.html). 
   With plovr, you can define a configuration that contains one file or multiple files.  All sensible ways of loading the code across multiple files (automatically generating multiple script tags / concatenating all files into 1 script / concatenating and minifying / compile with optimizations ) can then be adjusted by changing a single setting.

Plovr was designed by the author of [the one book on Google Closure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449381871), Michael Bolin, to help people use the Closure Compiler and Closure Library without having to set up a more complex build process.

Once you've got plovr up and running, correct usage of `goog.require()` and `goog.provide()` should really help you with writing code in manageably-sized files and using and concatenating the results.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I reference the same object in all files?

If you make it global, either declaring it with `var` in global scope, or set it as a property of `window`, then you can access it from everywhere.

> Is there a way to "bundle" them in a single javascript that will load all others ?

Yes, you can create `script` elements and append them to the DOM:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
for(var i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
   var current = script.cloneNode(false);
   current.src = "/Content/script/mzui.myproject.classlib.myClass"+i+".js";
   document.body.appendChild(current);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you better explain how to make it global though var ?

Comment: @Mendez If you declare it with `var` outside any function, it will be a global variable, and a property of `window`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QrLwT/)

Comment: I know that... what I don´t know is how to declare my "class" prototype  as global. Check this demo for correction: http://jsfiddle.net/4vaMp/ (not working).

Comment: @Mendez Your demo doesn't work because `myproject` is not defined, and you use `=` instead of `+` to concatenate strings. You should make sure that `myproject` is declared in global code, and then you will be able to access it from other scripts.

Comment: = was a type mistake... but what myproject should be equals to: var myproject = ??? Can you help me solve that in the fiddle ? I´m not getting the point... And that´s the point - how to make is a "class library".

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want to accomplish. I will elaborate in a new question.